# Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

I need to upgrade the sdk version to 31 because I tried to use **react native vision camera package**

In there it is recommend to upgrade to sdk version 31

here is the link https://mrousavy.com/react-native-vision-camera/docs/guides/troubleshooting/#android

This is my current AndroidManifest.html. As per other post from stack overflow post.
I already added "android:exported=true" to the main activity. But the error still here

[Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70333565/targeting-s-version-31-and-above-requires-that-an-explicit-value-for-android)

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.abc">

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>


        <application
            android:name=".MainApplication"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:allowBackup="false"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

         <!-- Change the value to true to enable pop-up for in foreground on receiving remote notifications (for prevent duplicating while showing local notifications set this to false) -->
        <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_foreground"
                    android:value="false"/>
        <!-- Change the resource name to your App's accent color - or any other color you want -->
        <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_color"
                    android:resource="@color/white"/> <!-- or @android:color/{name} to use a standard color -->

        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationActions" />
        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" />
        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

                 <service
            android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>


            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:exported="true"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
                android:launchMode="singleTask"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
                <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
</manifest>
```

This is the error log

```
> Task :app:installDebug FAILED
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Pixel_2_API_32(AVD) - 12' for app:debug

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
357 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 350 up-to-date
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Unable to install /Users/kerrydss/Desktop/Work/bhg-ecommerce-rn/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl227096480.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #76): ***com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present***
        at com.android.ddmlib.internal.DeviceImpl.installRemotePackage(DeviceImpl.java:1224)
```

When I try to add `android:exported=true` to the receiver line `receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver` above inter-filter the app is successfully built but always quit For inter-filter for `firebase push notification` the document recommend to `use android:export=false`. When I use false the app won't build

I start getting this error when I change the SDK version

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        ext {
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "+" // default: "+"
        firebaseMessagingVersion = "21.1.0" // default: "21.1.0"
       //working version without camera package
       // buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
       // minSdkVersion = 21
       // compileSdkVersion = 29
       // targetSdkVersion = 29
       // ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"


         buildToolsVersion = "30.0.0"
         minSdkVersion = 26
         compileSdkVersion = 31
         targetSdkVersion = 31
         ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2")
        classpath('com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.1')
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Comment: I have not tried add up `android:exported ` for application. But I do tried to add `android:exported ` to the receiver that wrap  `intent-filter `. The app is built but it always close by itself

Comment: Upgrade android studio, Update gradle versions and set exported= true/false for all activity/service/broadcast receivers.

Comment: I got the same issue. please help me out if you find any solution

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are using third party libraries that add some new components with a missing exported property. Click on the tab "Merged Manifest" when you have an xml file open with the manifest: see if there is a component and if it is found, just add it to your manifest with the android:exported="false" or "true" property. All components such as: activity, receivers, service must contain the android:exported field.

Answer (score 0):

```
AndroidManifest.xml
<receiver android:name=".NotificationReceiver" android:exported="true">
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.