# Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]

Tags: flutter, android-12

While debugging the application in android 12, the app is getting crashed.

Answer (score 233, accepted):

Android 12 require you to add a piece of code to your main activity

1. Go to your project folder and open AndroidManifest.xml file
2. Add the below code in activity

   `android:exported="true"`

**Reference:**

```
   <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme">
    </activity>
```

Comment: This property has to be set within the <activity> tag.

Comment: Can you be more specific about where it has to be added?

Comment: add in this file: android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: That seems to solve the problem, but still that answer needs clarification as of what does that parameter means and why set to true and not false for example.

Comment: Clear information is mentioned in the following document. link : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html?hl=es

Comment: Why is it needed? What does `android:exported="true"` mean / do?

Comment: @instanceof More info about that attribute can be found at https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/lets-be-explicit-about-our-intent-filters-c5dbe2dbdce0

Comment: Just to be clear, this answer is NOT GOOD. You need this attribute on EACH activity with an intent filter and on EACH service also. Again, thanks Android for those useless updates that breaks millions of deployments around the world! You're champions!

Comment: Also check your dependencies for updates. I my case the local_notifications plugin caused the error because the old plugin version did not set the exported property.

Comment: I added `android:exported="true"` but its still giving  the same issue

Comment: @NicolasBelley +1
Also, all `receiver`s with `intent-filters` must also include this property. So to sum up, `android:exported="true"` or `"false"` must be added to all `receiver`s, `service`s, and `activity` tags with `intent-filters` inside them.

Comment: works, I had to put it on all my activities, not just MainActivity

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have a extra dangling closing '>' at the end of this:  
android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme">
 </activity>

Answer (score 36):

In ***AndroidManifest.xml*** add `android:exported="true"`:

```
<manifest ...>
  <application ...>
    <activity
        android:exported="true"
```

Comment: This solved my issue when building in flutter, by placing `android:exported="true"` in app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 15):

In Android 11 and lower, when declaring an Activity, Service, or Broadcast receiver in AndroidManifest, you did not explicitly declare android:exported. Since the default value is exported=true, you only need to declare exported=false when you do not want to disclose to the outside.

```xml
<activity android:name="com.example.app.backgroundService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.app.START_BACKGROUND" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Android 12 Changes: Explicit declaration of exported
Apps that set SDK API 31 (android 12) as Target sdk on Android 12 devices must explicitly declare exported in components such as Activity that declared intent-filter. Otherwise, the following error occurs and the installation fails.

```
Targeting S+ (version 10000 and above) requires that an explicit value for
android:exported be defined when intent filters are present
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED
Even for apps targeting SDK API 31, components without intent-filter can omit the exported declaration.
```

You must explicitly declare exported as follows:

```xml
<service android:name="com.example.app.backgroundService"
         android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.app.START_BACKGROUND" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Intent-filter is one of the methods for exposing the app's component to the outside. This is because the component of my app can be executed through the resolving of the implicit intent.

On the other hand, there are many cases where it is used for the purpose of executing a component with an implicit intent only inside my app, but it is exposed to the outside because exported is not set, and this may affect the resolving of the implicit intent. .

Answer (score 9):

Thanks @rahul-kavati.

For Xamarin/MAUI it is a property on `ActivityAttribute`, used like this `[Activity(Label = "MsalActivity", Exported = true)]`

Comment: When I add this I get Error : System.InvalidOperationException: Duplicate attribute yet I've searched all my code and Exported is only defined once.  Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you have it more than once?

Comment: it's a xamarin android bug, https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/6463.  The fix is only for VS22 and I'm still running VS19

Answer (score 4):

In Xamarin.Android I faced the same in BroadcastReceiver:

```js
    [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported =true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { BluetoothDevice.ActionFound, BluetoothDevice .ActionUuid, BluetoothDevice .ExtraRssi})]
    public class BleReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
```

and solved with the same Exported=true

Answer (score 3):

The fastest way is to modify the `targetSdkVersion` in `app/build.gradle`, the maximum is `30`

Answer (score 2):

## In AndroidManifest.xml

```
     <activity
        android:exported="true"
        android:name="com.YOU.APP.activities.MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using any intent filter or service it must have the `android:export` property

Answer (score 0):

Currenty if you set minsdk version and get Android Error: Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined then I have sollution of that..

1. Open platforms/android/android.json
2. Put this line in all plugin you used.  android:exported="true" or android:exported="false" (Based on your requirement)

Image Link => https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uAtudZf5iRXUN2tWJvgxsaWeEuZmCUqh/view?usp=sharing

3. After open platforms\android\app\src\main/AndroidManifest.xml file and delete  the plugin activity,meta-data,service,provider..and other things under <application .......>
   ---Do not delete launcher activity (first activity)--
   ---delete other data---

Because we changed android.json line. So when we build again than It will auto generate with   android:exported..

I spend my whole day in this error. But now I am happy because I got Sollution.