# Flutter Android 12 install error when using intent-filter

Tags: flutter, android-manifest, intentfilter, android-12

I'm struggling with the error below.

```
adb: failed to install F:\xxx\src\FlutterDemoApp\FlutterDemoApp\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.
apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl1942767517.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #102): 

com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]
Error launching application on Pixel 4 XL.
```

As I found at [Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70333565/targeting-s-version-31-and-above-requires-that-an-explicit-value-for-android) and [Android Studio error: "Manifest merger failed: Apps targeting Android 12"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67412084/android-studio-error-manifest-merger-failed-apps-targeting-android-12) this is simply a matter of adding **android:exported="true"** to **android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml**

But the issue is it is already there in my environment and I still get the error.

Am I missing something else?

[image]

Comment: try to clean and run again

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26721951/install-parse-failed-manifest-malformed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried cleaning the project & changing package names to lowercase as advised in the comments. But nothing worked.
Below is what worked for me. Hope somebody fined this helpful.

I had to add Multi Dex support to my build.gradle

```
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.demo_app"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    multiDexEnabled = true //★This
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
implementation("androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1")//★This
implementation 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.19'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

}

Not exactly sure why this work, but you can read more here
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Answer (score 2):

Also make this in note,

> Starting from Android 12 (SDK 31) and when using intent-filter, the attribut android:exported must be set explicitly to false or true. Without this attribut the application wouldn't be able to be installed.
> References:

**Resource:**
[(contains the warning about installing an application without this attribut on Android 12 or higher)](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported)

When a `new flutter project` is created the default `AndroidManifest.xml` should contain this `attribute` set to `true` as the `intent` is a `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER:`

```
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="..."
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:exported="true"        <== SHOULD BE ADDED
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```