# Installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

Tags: java, android, android-studio

09/26 16:46:33: Launching 'app' on Pixel 6 Pro API 33.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

List of apks:
[0] '/Users/mac/Desktop/vault/code/Cal Vault/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: 'INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl913522096.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #93): com.example.vault.icon.icon_disguise0: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present'
Retry
Failed to launch an application on all devices

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70333565/targeting-s-version-31-and-above-requires-that-an-explicit-value-for-android

Answer (score 1):

you will need to set `android:exported="true"` or false to your activity/service/provider/receiver

in android studio.. open AndroidManifest.xml file and at bottom of the editor click on merged Manifest.. check which activity/service/provider/receiver doesn't have `android:exported="true"` or false.. and add it to your manifest as follow:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.ActivityWithoutExport"
    android:exported="true"
    tools:node="merge"/>
```

make sure to include `tools:node="merge"`