# Flutter Android Physical Device App Installation Failing: "App not installed as package appears to be invalid"

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, mobile-development

I have made an app in Flutter and am trying to install the apk on my physical device.I have done this *numerous times* in the past but recently I started getting this error when trying to install the apk:

--> **"App not installed as package appears to be invalid."**

Here are my specs, which hopefully will help:
Phone: Samsung S22+ (Android version 13, last updated Feb 2023)
Apk Installer: Package Installer (default one on the phone)
Method building apk: `flutter build apk` or `flutter build apk --build-name 1.1.0 --build-number 1`

android/app/src/main/build.gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ceventures.app.locationalerts.cedric.eicher"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: have you tried flutter clean, flutter doctor, and flutter pub get again.

Comment: Hi rvng, yes I have... Everything comes out with green checkmarks. No issues it picks up (I'm on the flutter stable channel, 3.7.9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

For anyone coming across this in the future, here's what finally worked for me. I hope you have the same luck since this was driving me crazy for weeks.

1. With the help of this post ([How do I run/test my Flutter app on a real device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54444538/how-do-i-run-test-my-flutter-app-on-a-real-device)), I was able to deploy directly to my physical device just like I would my emulator. To make it work, I had to do:
2. this ([Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70333565/targeting-s-version-31-and-above-requires-that-an-explicit-value-for-android)).

Following this, I was able to do your typical `flutter build apk` and install it on my device like before.

Hope this helps!!!